# I need to reduce the gap between the headings when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css

This the code i have used but, when i resize the browser, the space between the two headings for the tab view is not working. I should get the texts without the space when i resize the browser.Below is the html and css code i have used to make it happen but, its not working,could you please help me through this.

Here is the my code:

```css
 body {
     width: 100%;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
     padding: 0;
     display:block;
     padding-top: 100px;
     background-size:100%;
     margin: 0;

}

 #header{
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     background: #FFF;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

#carscene{
     width: 100%;
     height: 113vh;
     background: url('app-car-scene-min.png') no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     color: #FFF;
     font-family :"Source Sans Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     position: relative;
     background-position: top -175px left -2px;
     background-size: 108% 151%;

}

 #carscene #title-holder{
     position: absolute;
     top: 30vh;
     left: 8vw;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding-bottom: 50px;
     height: 6vw;
     width: 70vw;
}

 #carscene #title-holder h1{
     position: absolute;
     font-size: 5vw;
     font-weight: bold;
     animation: emerge-up 2s ease-out;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     top: 6%;
     animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes emerge-up {
     0% {
         top: 250%;
    }
     10% {
         top: 250%;
    }
     65% {
         top: -15%;
    }
     100% {
         top: 5%;
    }
}

 @keyframes emerge-up {
     0% {
         top: 250%;
    }
     10% {
         top: 250%;
    }
     65% {
         top: -15%;
    }
     100% {
         top: 5%;
    }
}

#everymin {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    background: #abc;
}

#carscene h2 {
     position: absolute;
     font-size: 2vw;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 0;
     padding-left: 13.5vw;
     top: 48vh;
     left:-8vh;
     opacity: 0;
     animation-delay: 1.5s;
     transform: scale(0);
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

 .scale-in {
     transform: scale(1);
     animation-name: scaleIn;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease;
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes scaleIn {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
         transform: scale(0.8);
    }
     50% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     100% {
         opacity: 1;
         transform: scale(1);
    }
}

 @keyframes scaleIn {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
         transform: scale(0.8);
    }
     50% {
         opacity: 1;
    }
     100% {
         opacity: 1;
         transform: scale(1);
    }
}

#carscene #title-button {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 52vh;
     left: 9.5vw;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 11vh;
     width: 50vw;
     animation-duration: 3.5s;
     top:57vh;
}

#carscene h3 {
     position: absolute;
     width: 18vw;
     font-size: 2.5vh;
     background: #35baf2;
     height: 6vh;
     margin: -1px;
     padding-top: 20px;
     left: 0vh;
     bottom: 100px;
     border-radius: 9px;
     text-align: center;
     animation: emerge-down 1.5s ease forwards;
     animation-delay: 2.2s;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes emerge-down {
     0% {
        bottom: 100px;
    }
     100% {
        bottom: 15px;
    }
}
 @keyframes emerge-down {
     0% {
        bottom: 100px;
    }
     100% {
        bottom: 15px;
    }
}

#carscene #title-check {
     position: absolute;
     top: 67vh;
     left: -8vw;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 20vh;
     width: 50vw;
}

#carscene ul{
     position: absolute;
     font-size: 1.6vw;
     margin: 0;
     padding-left: 13.5vw;
     top: -8%;
     list-style: none;
     white-space:pre;
     animation-duration: 6s;
     transition: transform .4s ease-in-out, opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

 .fa-check-square-o:before {
   content: "\f046";
   font-size: 90%;
   color: rgb(0,206,89);
}

 .fade-in {
     animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
     animation-delay: 3s;
     opacity: 0;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
 @keyframes fadeInOpacity {
      0% {
         opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

    #carscene{
        background: url('app-car-scene-min.png') no-repeat;
        background-position: right 20% bottom -251px;
        background-size:333% 140%;
        width:100%;
        height:116%;






     }

    #carscene #title-holder {
        height: 13vw;
        width: 80vw;
        top: 10vh;
        left: 11vw;
        max-height:100%;

    }

    #carscene #title-holder h1 {
        font-size: 8.5vw;
    }

    #carscene h2 {
        font-size: 4vw;
        padding-left: 10.5vw;
        top: 19vh;
        left:0vh;

    }

    #carscene #title-button {
        left: 23vw;
        height: 9vh;
        top: 26vh;
        border-radius:6px;

    }

    #carscene h3 {
        width: 52vw;
        font-size: 2.5vh;
        height: 6vh;
        border-radius:3px;
        min-height:100%;


    }

    #carscene #title-check {
        top: 35vh;
        left: 0vw;
        width: 100%;
     }

    #carscene ul {
        font-size: 4.2vw;
        white-space:inherit;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        left:7vh;
        top:2%;

    }

    li {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 5%;

    }

    #everymin {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    background: #abc;
  }

} 


@media (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 778px) {

    #carscene{
        background: url('app-car-scene-min.png') no-repeat;
        background-position:right -125px bottom 399px;
        background-size: 150% 80%;
        width:105%;
        height:127%;
        position:relative;
    }

 #carscene #title-holder {
        top: 3vh;
        left: 8vw;
        height: 33vw;
        width: 30vw;
        position:absolute;

    }

   #carscene #title-holder h1 {
        font-size: 8vw;
        top:6%;
     }

    #carscene h2 {
        padding-left: 6.5vw;
        font-size: 3vw;
        top: 31vh;
        left:0vh;
        width:100%;     
    }

     #carscene #title-text {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50vw;
        top: -4vh;

    } 

    #carscene #title-button {
        height: 11vh;
        width: 50vw;
        max-height:100%;
        top: 34vh;
        left: 5vw;
        position:absolute; 
    }

    #carscene h3 {
        width: 43vw;
        overflow:auto;
        margin:2px;
        padding-top:24px;
        font-size:2.5vh;      
    }

    #carscene ul {
        font-size: 27px;
        padding-left:0.5vw;
        overflow:auto;
        position:absolute;  
    }

    #carscene #title-check {
        top: 43vh;
        left: -6vw;

    }
}



@media (min-width: 779px) and (max-width: 1024px){

    #carscene {

        background: url('app-car-scene-min.png') no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        width:107%;
        height:122%;
    }

    #carscene #title-holder h1 {
        font-size: 5.3vw;
    }

    #carscene #title-holder {
        top: 15vh;
        left: 8vw;
    }

    #carscene h2 {
        top: 23vh;
        left: -5vw;
        font-size:2.3vw;
    }

    #carscene h3 {
        width: 38vw;

    }

    #carscene #title-button {
        left: 9vw;
        top: 25vh;
        width:36vw;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #carscene #title-check {
        top: 29vh;
        left: -11vw;
    }

    #carscene ul {
        font-size: 2.7vw;
        top:25%;

    }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Lucep Banner work</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='banner.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">Lucep logo header</div>
  <div id="carscene">
     <div id="title-holder">
        <h1>Capture. Call. Convert.</h1>
     </div>
     <div id="title-text">
     <h2 class="scale-in">Call back customers faster than your competition</h2>
     </div>
     <div id="title-button">
        <h3>Start Your Free Trial &#x25BA;</h3>
     </div>
     <div id="title-check" class="fade-in">
        <ul>
           <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa_custom"> No credit card required</i>
           <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa_custom"> 30 day free trial</i>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div id="everymin">
    <h1>Every minute matters</h1>
    bla bla bla
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code was it doesn't have equalized height formatting for each div in the body section.Adjust them in relative way to get your web page.